# How to understand this objective function in deep learning

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, deep-learning

I'm going through Christopher Manning's tutorial from NAACL 2013 "Deep Learning for NLP (without Magic)" and he gets to the point where he's showing how to do unsupervised pre-training. He's saying that we compute two different scores $s$ and $s_c$ and then we want to train the network so that $s > s_c$. He claims that the objective function to use is

$$
J = \text{max}(0, 1 - s + s_c)
$$

I don't see how minimizing this function ensures that $s > s_c$. It seems to me that the value is greater than zero whenever the sum of $s$ and $s_c$ is greater than 1 and it doesn't matter which one is greater than the other.

Could someone help clear this up for me? What am I missing?

The video is here: http://techtalks.tv/talks/deep-learning-for-nlp-without-magic-part-1/58414/ and the part I'm asking about is at about the 50:30 mark. The slides are at http://nlp.stanford.edu/courses/NAACL2013/NAACL2013-Socher-Manning-DeepLearning.pdf and the slide in question is number 50.

Comment: Are you perhaps typing or reading the formula incorrectly?  As written here, it does not involve the "sum of $s$ and $s_c$": it involves their *difference*.  (The server for your reference is so slow that I could not review the slides to check and it's unlikely most other readers would succeed in doing that, either.)

Comment: The formula is correct and now that I've read your comment and thought about it some more I see my mistake. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

> Are you perhaps typing or reading the formula incorrectly? As written here, it does not involve the "sum of $s$ and $s_c$": it involves their difference.

---

I've copied @whuber's comment as an answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.

- [Are we seeing a dramatic drop in answers per question?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/are-we-seeing-a-dramatic-drop-in-answers-per-question/5320#5320)
- [Comments that are actually answers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/comments-that-are-actually-answers)
- [We have a very large & widening gap between questions and answers. How do we fix it?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/we-have-a-very-large-widening-gap-between-questions-and-answers-how-do-we-fix)